# Create a function to insert into a table from another table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, sql-function

I have created some types and then a table that has these types:

```
Create Type Data_typ AS (
... );

Create Type Communication_typ As (
...;

Create Type CreditCard_typ As (
...);

Create Type Name_typ As (
...);

Create Type Personal_typ As (
...);

Create Type Address_typ As (
...);

Create Type Customers_typ As (
CustomerID integer,
Data Data_typ,
Communication Communication_typ,
CreditCard CreditCard_typ,
Name Name_typ,
Personal Personal_typ,
Address Address_typ);

Create Table Customers_1 of Customers_typ(
primary key (CustomerID));
```

Also, I have another table, named `customers` that has some data in it. What I want to do is to create a function that will copy all the elements from customers into customers_1. The columns of `customers` are the same as customers_1,but on customers_1 I have created types that include some of the columns.

('Customers' has 20 columns, and I have broken that into the 6 types that are on Customers_1).

Here is my function:

```
Create OR REPLACE Function CopyCustomers() RETURNS VOID AS
$$
Begin 
    Insert Into Customers_1(
    Select
    NEW Data_typ (username, password),
    new communication_typ(email,phone),
    new creditCard_typ(creditcardtyp,creditcard,creditcardexpiration),
    new name_typ(firstname,lastname),
    new personal(age,income,gender),
    new address(address1,address2,coty,state,zip)
    From Customers);

End;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'm not sure if the `new` is correct. The error I get is

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 7:  NEW Data_typ (username, password),
                      ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
SQL state: 42601
Character: 119
```

---

**Update**  - I tried using the `ROW` syntax:

```
Create OR REPLACE Function CopyCustomers() RETURNS VOID AS
$$
Begin 
    Insert Into Customers_1
    Select
    ROW(username, password),
    ROW(email,phone),
    ROW(creditcardtyp,creditcard,creditcardexpiration),
    ROW(firstname,lastname),
    ROW(age,income,gender),
    ROW(address1,address2,coty,state,zip)
    From Customers;

End;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I execute the Function, and I get an error:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type record to data_typ
LINE 4:  ROW(username, "Password"),
         ^
QUERY:  Insert Into Customers_1
    Select
    CustomerID,
    ROW(username, password),
    ROW(email,phone),
    ROW(creditcardcype,creditcard,creditcardexpiration),
    ROW(firstname,lastname),
    ROW(age,income,gender),
    ROW(address1,address2,city,state,zip)
    From CustomerS
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function copycustomers() line 3 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: cannot cast type record to data_typ
SQL state: 42846
Context: PL/pgSQL function copycustomers() line 3 at SQL statement
```

Comment: While it's good to edit your questions in response to new information, please don't *replace* what was already there. Now existing answers like mine make no sense; I seem to be talking about something completely different to what you wrote. I fixed it for you.

Comment: You still have the `SELECT` in parentheses. That doesn't make sense. remove them - the `(` after `Customers_`, and the `)` before the `;` should both be removed. Then run it in `psql`. Show how you execute the function too.

Comment: The parentheses where a typo, I had removed them

Comment: OK, now, read my answer again. What did I say, after I already told you about the parentheses, when I mentioned casts? See how I *cast* the `ROW(..)` to the *target type* for the field?

Comment: Okay, now this solved my problem, but I get another error `ERROR:  value too long for type character(2)`. I saw some other questions about this,but couldn't solve it. I think I'll ask a different question about this, cos it's a different problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of problems.

```
Insert Into Customers_1(
Select
```

You don't need the paren there, it's just

```
INSERT INTO customers_1 SELECT ....
```

As for this:

```
NEW Data_typ (username, password),
```

are you just trying to create a `Data_typ`, where `Data_typ` is a composite type created with `CREATE TYPE Data_typ AS (...)` ?

If so, you want:

```
ROW(username, password)::xy
```

example, given `CREATE TYPE xy AS (x integer, y integer);`:

```
regress=> SELECT new xy(1,2);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: SELECT new xy(1,2);
                     ^
regress=> SELECT xy(1,2);
ERROR:  function xy(integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT xy(1,2);
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
regress=> SELECT ROW(1,2)::xy;
  row  
-------
 (1,2)
(1 row)
```

Comment: Do I need to `create type` if I have the `Row`? I'm confused where to put `row`

Comment: @Shevliaskovic Well, you wrote `new communication_typ(email, phone)`. That's nonsense syntax. Instead use `ROW(email, phone)`; PostgreSQL should figure out that the destination column is of type `communication_typ`; if it doesn't, explicitly cast the row to `communication_typ`.

Comment: Okay about that. But the insert doesn't work. I wrote the `row` and then executed it.After that I executed `Select * From customers_1;`,but I don't get any result. The table is empty.